# Why we include Google Tag Manager script of nearly 7 - 8 lines?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

What is the importance of the below code??

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MHT6T5W');</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read this article https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2016/11/22/where-should-google-tag-manager-snippet-be-placed/

### What Does This Code Do?

Let’s examine the container code and see what it’s actually doing.

In the first part, we see a script tag. The script inside of here is a JavaScript function that loads your specific container on your page. It does this by creating a new script tag and setting the source to the url to your Tag Manager container. This is the important part; it goes in the head.

It also tells your page to load your GTM container asynchronously, which means that the rest of the page can continue loading while Google is doing its magic.

In the second part, we see a no script tag. This works as a backup, allowing you to track users without Javascript (which, will not be much.) The no script tag tells the browser, if the user does not have JavaScript enabled, then render an iframe version of the GTM Container to the page. Certain Tags and pixels can be configured to still load properly, even for those without JavaScript. This part of the snippet goes in the body, and is really only important if you care about tracking non-JS users.